# ServiceStack with IdentityServer

Tags: servicestack, identityserver4

Using the template at https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/mvcidentityserver
and trying to require Authorization to access the ServiceStack "Hello" object.

I'm able to retrieve a token and call

https://localhost:5001/servicestack-identity

and

https://localhost:5001/webapi-identity

from PostMan successfully.

However, if I add an Authenticate attribute

```
namespace MyApp.ServiceInterface
{
    public class MyServices : Service
    {
        [Authenticate]
        public object Any(Hello request)
        {
            return new HelloResponse { Result = $"Hello, {request.Name}!" };
        }
```

to the Any method in MyServices, I'm not able to call /Hello with the token.

[image: /Hello fails]

/requiresauth gives the same result

[image: /requiresauth]

Comment: Do you have a successful response if you do not add the Authenticate attribute?

Comment: yes, /Hello works if I don't add [Authenticate]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by adding the following to MyApp.Startup.ConfigureServices()...

```
  services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
                .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options => {
                    options.Authority = "https://localhost:5000";
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                    options.Audience = "api1";
                });
```